# Initializing and comparing integers

Tags: java

Besides the syntax, is there a difference (performance, semantics, etc.) between these two ways to initialize `Integer`s?

```
Integer i = new Integer(10);
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(10);
```

And is there a difference between these two ways to compare an `Integer` for equality against a constant?

```
i.equals(CONSTANT);
(CONSTANT).equals(i);
```

Answer (score 5):

`new Integer(10)` creates a new integer object.

`Integer.valueOf(10)` may potentially return an interned instance of the object.  Java keeps a pool of freqeuently used integers (generally) the small ones.

`i.equals(CONSTANT)` and `CONSTANT.equals(i)` differ in behaviour only when `i` is `null`.  I prefer the second form since it's more null safe.

Answer (score 3):

- `new Integer(10)` will always create a new `Integer` object with the value `10`.
- `Integer.valueOf(10)` will return a `Integer` object with the value `10` from a pool (the pool only contains a limited range of values, numbers outside of this pool will return a new `Integer` object as well).
- `i.equals(CONSTANT)` will throw a `NullPointerException` when `i` is `null`.
- `CONSTANT.equals(i)` will never throw a `NullPointerException` (assuming `CONSTANT` is a non-null `static final` field and its `equals()` method is sane).

Answer (score 1):

As Java Doc for Integer.valueOf says,

> Returns a Integer instance representing the specified int value. If a
>   new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be
>   used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), **as this method is
>   likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by
>   caching frequently requested values**.
>
> > **Parameters:**
> >     i an int value.
> >
> > **Returns:**
> >     a Integer instance representing i.
> >
> > **Since:**
> >     1.5

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) explains the first.

`CONSTANT.equals(i)` will not throw `NUllPointerExcpetion` obviously unless `CONSTANT` is null.

Comment: ...unless it's a `null` constant. o_O

Answer (score 1):

1. `Integer.valueOf(int)` has better performance because it caches values between -128 and 127.
2. Nothing, except when `i` is `null`. The latter should be used to deal with this case instead of having an extraneous `if` check.